# Is cyber sex forbidden? How is it forbidden, what are the punishments, and rectifications?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality

As I've been advised, [cyber sex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersex) (with a jew or goy) is forbidden, but I'm unsure as to what specifically causes it to be forbidden, what the punishments are for performing it, and what rectifications may exist for it. I've been told just because it's not subject to Karet doesn't mean it's okay, but I don't know specifically how "not okay" it is.

As a summary, from wikipedia:

> Cybersex, also called computer sex, Internet sex, netsex, e-sex and,
> colloquially, cyber or cybering, is a virtual sex encounter in which
> two or more people have long distance sex via electronic video
> communication (webcams, VR headsets, etc) and other electronics (such
> as teledildonics) connected to a computer network.
>
> Cybersex can also mean sending each other sexually explicit messages
> without having sex, and simply describing a sexual experience (also
> known as "sexting") Cybersex is a sub-type of technology-mediated
> sexual interactions.In one form, this is accomplished by the
> participants describing their actions and responding to their chat
> partners in a mostly written form designed to stimulate their own
> sexual feelings and fantasies. Cybersex often includes real life
> masturbation.

As you can see, this does not have to involve pornography at all, but is more a form of highly promiscuous behaviour taking place over long distance and not face-to-face.

Comment: Bro just don’t do it

Comment: If people are going to close this for pornography, they have should have the courtesy to explain exactly how cyber sex is equated to pornography. It seems clear that there are more issues with it and it should NOT be closed as a dupe

Comment: Thank you @RabbiKaii for your honesty and sincerity in wanting to help me. You've been truly helpful.

Comment: @hopingitsokay you've got my email, feel free to reach out

Comment: Wasting seed is forbidden, and that's pretty much the whole point of the activity you're asking about

Comment: @יהושעק According to [Mishneh Torah Issurei Biah 21:19](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960669/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twenty-One.htm#v19), so are intentionally causing oneself to have an erection, or to bringing oneself to sexual thoughts, which are even more the point of such activity, even when conceivably no seed is actually wasted (however impossible that may practically be).

Comment: @TamirEvan the Rambam, the Gemarra and the Shulchan Aruch all rule that way, absolutely. But I think the Ikar of such videoconferences is that the eyes see, the heart desires, and the body sins

Comment: Also even purposefully gazing at a woman is not permitted per the Gemara; see my answer here for the source (Avodah Zarah 20a-b): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136870/is-it-permissible-to-use-an-anime-drawing-as-a-profile-picture-online-if-the-cha/136972#136972

Comment: Strictly speaking, the suggested duplicate question is about pornography, meaning depictions of erotic behavior in pictures or writing that are intended to cause sexual excitement. This question is about the subject of remote sexual encounters between individuals via tools. (think for example about stimulation with a different tool, like a vibrator) It doesn't fall under the category of pornography either. This is a different question and worth being addressed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is all forbidden. It falls under the general prohibitions enumerated in Chapter 18 of VaYikra.

Some of the most germane posukim are:

> ***You shall not copy the practices of the land of Egypt where you dwelt, or of the land of Canaan*** to which I am taking you; ***nor shall you follow their laws***.
>
> None of you men ***shall come near*** anyone of his own flesh to uncover nakedness: I am יהוה.

Coming near includes even with words, texts, or any other type of electronic communication.

> ***Do not allow any of your offspring to be offered up*** to Molech, and do not profane the name of your God: I am יהוה.

Among other things, **"offering your offspring to Molech"** means *any type of activity which encourages and stimulates sexual arousal* which will ***potentially result*** in wasting of seed *solely for the purpose of sexual gratification*.

> ***Do not defile yourselves in any of those ways***, for it is by such that the nations that I am casting out before you defiled themselves.
>
> But you must keep My laws and My rules, and ***you must not do any of those abhorrent things***, neither the citizen nor the stranger who resides among you;
> ***for all those abhorrent things were done by the people who were in the land before you***, and the land became defiled.
>
> ***All who do any of those abhorrent things—such persons shall be cut off from their people.***
> You shall ***keep My charge not to engage in any of the abhorrent practices*** that were carried on before you, and you shall not defile yourselves through them: I יהוה am your God.

All of these types of behavior are referred to as *Abhorrent* תועבה.

Like the last sentence quoted above, ***all who do any of these things shall be cut off***.

**נכרתו הנפשות העשת מקרב עמם**

Regarding the much broader subject of: What are the Tikkunim for this? The first step is simply to stop the behavior.

What particular tikkunim would be relevant to the individual, spiritually, would be better directed to their local Orthodox Rabbi and their personal spiritual counselor, called a *Mashpia*.

Comment: Thank you, @Yaacov Deane! This was helpful and informative, and I am grateful for your contribution.

Comment: @hopingitsokay You're welcome, of course. It's worth pointing out a small detail from the last sentence quoted that is often overlooked in translation. נכרתו הנפשות העשת מקרב עמם means that they will be cut off from among "their people". It is not only directed to the Jewish people, which would be "your people" עמך. It means that this type of behavior is prohibited for everyone and damaging to all people.